# ASP.NET get count of result from HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a working HttpResponseMessage that returns data, my question is how do I count of the data?

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
     httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.com/");
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
     httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
     HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("v1/registrants/search?email=" + email).Result;
     return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Please help.

This is what it returns:

```
{
  "links" : {
    "next" : null
  },
  "items" : [ ]
}
```

If items is empty that means the count should be 0.

And this is what it returns when its not empty

```
{
    "links": {
        "next": null
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "registrantId": 31436518,
            "personalId": 38464352,
            "firstName": "FirstName",
            "lastName": "LastName",
            "email": "email@domain.com",
            "address": ", Stoney Creek, , 90210, ",
            "phone": "9053341529",
            "_links": {
                "self": "/registrants/31436518"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you also post what data you are getting from the API ?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: and what if items is not empty ?

Comment: I would suggest to use c# dynamic types if you don't know the structure of the response.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [JSON.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to parse the JSON.

First define a class to which models the results:

```
class ResultModel
{
  public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Then call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(string json)` to parse / map the result:

```
using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
   httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.com/");
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
   HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("v1/registrants/search?email=" + email).Result;
   string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   ResultModel result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultModel>(json);
   int count = result.items.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Install the Nuget [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) before proceeding.**

---

**1) Deserialize the serialized string response into a [JObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm)**

```
public async Task<JObject> FetchData()
{
    using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
         httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.com/");
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
         HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("v1/registrants/search?email=" + email).Result;
         string response = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(response);
    }
}
```

**2) Call the [`.Count()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.7.2) method on it, use the combination of [safe-evaluation operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator#C#) with [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) to fallback if `items` is not present.**

```
public async Task<int> CalculateCount()
{
    JObject responseObject = await FetchData();
    return responseObject["items"]?.Count() ?? 0;
}
```